# Calculate and submit form values with jquery and ajax and add calculated values to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I can not figure out how to calculate different form values and submit calculated values to an empty div on another page. I don't have any php or similar, this should be just a dummy page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my current html and jquery code:

**HTML:**

```
<form class="wrapper" id="form" action="" name="">
    <input class="input" type="range" min="18" max="90" value="22" id="age" data-amount>
    <select class="input" name="" id="" data-amount>
        <option value="50">Old</option>
    </select>
    <input class="input" type="radio" name="" value="40" id="" data-amount>   
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Find best match">
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var total = 0;
    var amount = '[data-amount]';

    $(amount).each(function(index){
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "result.html",
        amount: total,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#result').html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve ? Are you posting values from ajax to a different page asynchronously ?

Comment: the point of ajax is that you don't leave your current page so if you need to show the result on a new page then you shouldn't be using ajax

Comment: What do you mean by "submit to an empty div on another page"? Are you trying to change "result.html" on the server? That won't work without a backend.

Comment: Thanks for the fast respond guys. If it's not possible to redirect to another page e.g. result.html without backend, can I simply load a calculated content to the current page, in this case, index.html. Then the point would be to hide the existing content (design) from index.html and show calculated which has a totally different design.

Comment: I think this is a demo form ( single option and single radio button? ).. Have you tried form action? [this](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) might help..

Comment: @millan you can do that with javascript jquery..

Comment: @T.Adak yes but how? :D I prefer more jquery with no pure javascript

Comment: @mickbrancco.. I'm not sure what calculation OP needs to do with the form data.. But after that existing div can be hidden by $().hide() and new div can be shown with $().show().. Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [this](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) out

Comment: There are some dummy values on inputs e.g. value="22" for input type range, value="50" on option element, value="40" for type radio etc, so I want to sum these values with jquery and by clicking input submit put overall values in specific div if possible on another page, if not it's acceptable to be on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably work and satisfy your need. Not tested though:

HTML:

```
<form class="wrapper" id="form" action="" name="">
    <input class="input" type="range" min="18" max="90" value="22" id="age" data-amount>
    <select class="input" name="" id="" data-amount>
        <option value="50">Old</option>
    </select>
    <input class="input" type="radio" name="" value="40" id="" data-amount>   
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Find best match">
</form>
<div id="result-container" style="display:none">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var total = 0;
    var amount = '[data-amount]';

    $(amount).each(function(index){
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $("#result-container").html(total);
    $("#result-container").show();
    $("form").hide();
    return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks @pathrik this did a job!